# Set a max value for MYSQL field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently using the following code to update a certain field every hour

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `admin_wp12`.`wp_usermeta` SET  meta_value=meta_value+3 WHERE `wp_usermeta`.`umeta_id` =17;");
```

However, I want it to stop increasing when the meta_value reaches 300.

I really don't get the use of the MAX function, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow a value like 299 to be updated as 300, you could use the [`LEAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function
 like this:

```
UPDATE `admin_wp12`.`wp_usermeta`
SET
  meta_value=LEAST(300, meta_value+3)
WHERE
 `wp_usermeta`.`umeta_id` = 17
 AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value` < 300
```

Answer (score 2):

Just update fields with `meta_value` equal or lower than 297 (because on 297 we will allow one more increase to 300).

```
UPDATE `admin_wp12`.`wp_usermeta`
SET meta_value=meta_value + 3
WHERE `wp_usermeta`.`umeta_id` = 17
   AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value` <= 297
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional condition to the end of your query

```
UPDATE admin_wp12.wp_usermeta 
SET  meta_value = meta_value + 3 
WHERE umeta_id = 17
AND meta_value <= 297
```